# Why the snapshot of a view can look twice too big in some cases?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, snapshot

## ISSUE

When using various `UIView` extensions to take a snapshot of a `UIView`, the result can appear bigger (kind of zoomed in) than it should be.

### Details on the Issue

I take snapshots of 2 `UIViews`, that we can call viewA and viewB in what follows.

- **viewA**:
  The view is added to the view hierarchy when the snapshot is created.
- **viewB**:
  The is fully defined but *has not been added yet* to the view hierarchy when the snapshot is created. The snapshot is then cropped x number of times and the result is added to some `UIView` for display.

I have tested 3 different codes to obtain the result I am looking for: one provides the desired snapshot images but with low quality rendering; the other two provides better quality image rendering and the right result for **viewA** but for **viewB**, although the snapshot appears to have the right rect (I checked the rects), the images shown appear too big (as if they were zoomed in twice).

## CODE

1. **Extension #1**: Provides the right results but with low quality image

   ```
   extension UIView {

       func takeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
           self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
           let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

           return snapshot
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Extension #2**: Provides the right image quality but cropped images of viewB are displayed twice too big

   ```
   extension UIView {
       func snapshot(of rect: CGRect? = nil, afterScreenUpdates: Bool = true) -> UIImage {
           return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect ?? bounds).image { _ in
               drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Extension #3**: Likewise, provides the right image quality but cropped images of viewB are displayed twice too big

   ```
   extension UIView {
       func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

           drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
           let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

           if (image != nil) { return image! }
           return UIImage()
       }
   }
   ```

Last but not least, a (simplified) code to extract cropped images from the snapshot

```
    for i in (0...numberOfCroppedImages) {
        let rect    = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * snapshot!.size.width / CGFloat(numberOfCroppedImages), y: 0, width: snapshot!.size.width / CGFloat(numberOfCroppedImages), height:snapshot!.size.height)

        // defines the container view for the fragmented snapshots
        let view    = UIView()
        view.frame  = rect


        // defines the layer with the fragment of the snapshot
        let layer           = CALayer()
        layer.frame.size    = rect.size
        let img             = snapshot?.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect)
        layer.contents      = img
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```

### Attempted actions so far

I have doubled checked the all the `CGRect` and I have not found any issue with them: the view rectangles as well as the snapshot sizes seem to be the one expected, yet, I keep having too large rendered images with extension #2 & #3 for *viewB* (viewA is properly rendered), whilst extension #1 gives images of the right sizes but with too low quality to be adequately used.

Could it be an issue with `drawInHierarchy(in: afterScreenUpdates:)`? or alternatively the conversion to cgImage with
`let img = snapshot?.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect)` ?

I'd be very thankful for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a solution I have found that works for me:

First, a snapshot extension that renders (for my case) the expected results (both quality and size wise) whether the view is added to hierarchy or not, cropped or not:

```
    extension UIView {

        func takeSnapshot(of rect: CGRect? = nil, afterScreenUpdates: Bool = true) -> UIImage {
            return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect ?? bounds).image { (context) in
                self.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            }
        }

    }
```

Then the updated version of the code that takes a snapshot of a rect in a view:

```
    let view    = UIView()
    view.frame  = rect
    let img = self.takeSnapshot(of: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true).cgImage
    view.layer.contents = img
```

The difference here consists in taking a snapshot of a rectangle in the view instead of cropping the snapshot of the whole view.

I hope this helps.